# PNG file as figure generates character error

Tags: tikz-pgf, png

In an Overleaf article I import a [image: PNG file] produced with GIMP as follows:

```
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
        \input{global_time_space_v02.png}    
    \caption{\label{fig:global_time_space}Global time-space representation}
\end{figure}
```

And I get an error:

```
./global_time_space_v02.png:2: Text line contains an invalid character. l.2 ^^Z
```

If I convert to JPG or TIFF the same error occurs with different characters:

```
./Figures/global_time_space_v02.jpg:1: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard charact er used is undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.1 � ���^^@^^PJFIF^^@^^A^^A^^@^^@^^A^^@^^A^^@^^@��^^@C^^@^^H^^F^^F^^G^^F^^E^...
```

I am using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: You need \includegraphics{global_time_space_v02} not \input  (and naturally the graphicx package).

Comment: Voting to close as the problem has been solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) proposed, it needs `\includegraphics{global_time_space_v02}` and not `\input{global_time_space_v02.png}` (and naturally the graphicx package).